# Oracle Apex Select list with Cascading LOV Parent Item AND 2 parents with dependencies

Tags: oracle, list, dependencies, cascading, lov

I have the following problem:

**First:**
Two select lists (A & B) with years depending on each other.
When List A has a selected year, list B should have the entry 'Alle'. And also the other way round.

*Works fine with a dynamic action.*

**Second:**
Depending on those two Items i have more items with A & B as "Cascading LOV Parent"
Works fine two, BUT the first list-item does not get the change.

-

```
Example: A=2013 B=Alle

Change B to 2014

(Firebug:)
List-item 1 (C):

p_arg_names A

p_arg_names B

p_arg_values    **2013**

p_arg_values    2014

-

List-item 2 (D):

p_arg_names A

p_arg_names B

p_arg_names C

p_arg_values    **Alle**

p_arg_values    2014

p_arg_values    Alle

-
```

The SQL in list-item C depends on A & B and does not work right because of the wrong value.

-

Do you understand what i mean? Is there hope? I'm thinking about a radio-button to make the user choose first, which year(-column) he wants to use, but thats not what i want.

Thx and regards

Comment: Now i used a second dynamic action with "change on A & B" -> refresh C. Deleted all "Cascading LOV Parent"-A&B-entries. Is there a better way?